# distinguishing Listbox click, touch, scroll?

Tags: smart-mobile-studio

I am still having a hard time with a Listbox and distinguishing between "touch" to select and item in a listbox on a desktop/laptop browser.....and "touch" to begin scrolling (e.g. on a phone/tablet)

Using a basic example listbox with 100 items

```
procedure TForm1.Resize;
var i: integer;
begin
  inherited;
  W3ListBox1.Clear;
  for i:= 1 to 100 do
   W3ListBox1.Add('Item ' + inttostr(i));
  W3ListBox1.SetBounds(0,0,width,height);
end;
```

When a user is using the desktop/laptop browser, I need them to be able to use both mouse and touch (case their monitor is touch) to "scroll" and "select" item.....else if using their phone or tablet, need them to be able to use "touch" to scroll and "tap" to select item

I assume we dont want to use the standard OnSelected event ?

W3ListBox1..OnSelected := HandleLBItemSelected;

and probably want to use the OnTouchBegin & OnTouchEnd, as well as the OnMouseDown & OnMouseUp  events??????

If So, how?

And how do you then handle the scrolling?

Answer (score 1):

When this question was asked, Smart Mobile Studio's ListBox had problems with scrolling and these events. TW3ListBox in the current version (3.0) has a completely new listbox, which works properly in both desktop and mobile platforms.